# Python datetime module can't change variable parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am a beginner. I tried running this on Jupyter Notebook.

```
x = 5
y = dt.date.today() + dt.timedelta(days = x)
print(y)
x = 1000
print(y)
```

and the result was

```
2020-08-01
2020-08-01
```

I don't understand why if x changes from 5 to 1000 days, y won't change either. Does the timedelta save the 5 input? Am I missing something with these parameters?

Comment: The assignment `y = dt.date.today() + dt.timedelta(days = x)` calls the value of `x` when `y` is created. Since there is no new assignment to `y` in between the two print statements, `y` won't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get the question right, you perceive `y` to behave like a function. Which is not the case in your code; it's a variable. As a contrasting example, if you assign a function to `y` instead, you get

```
import datetime as dt

def y(x):
    return dt.date.today() + dt.timedelta(days=x)

# equivalent lambda expression:
# y = lambda x: dt.date.today() + dt.timedelta(days=x)

x = 5
print(y(x))
# 2020-08-01

x = 1000
print(y(x))
# 2023-04-23
```

Note that now, there is only one assignment to `y` (which gets a little more clear if you look at the `lambda` expression). However, in each print statement, the function `y` is *called* (noticeable by the parentheses `()` after the function's name) with the variable `x` as input.

Comment: Ah, so once I define y as a variable, I can't "edit it" by changing x. y will stay the same because at the time x was 5, so y was defined as having 5 days, not x days? So, the only way to change the variable y is to redefine it?

Comment: @RaviB. yes, in your code you'd have to assign a new value to `y` since it's immutable. See also the link posted by Schiz, and a [nice blog post here](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you print y value.
Asigning 1000 to x does not change anything unless you will add is (as timedelta) to y.

So your `y` is `2020-08-01` - it's defined here:

```
y = dt.date.today() + dt.timedelta(days = x)
```

This takes the value of `x` in the time when y is assigned (`x` = 5).

Changing `x` in following lines affects only `x`, it does not force everything to recalculate (`y` does not recalculate, till you write code for that).

Comment: Sorry, I put the wrong output. It should have said the dates instead of days.

Answer (score 0):

This is because python works with "passing by assignment"

https://medium.com/school-of-code/passing-by-assignment-in-python-7c829a2df10a

Comment: Did you really read whole article? It's about mutable and immutable types.

Comment: Oops.. It was not an appropriate document for this matter.

Comment: It's very interesting article, and can enhance knowledge - but in python it's not about passing by assignment. Check passing int and list (as it's show in article :))

Comment: The problem was that the re-calculation of y was missing.